# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object Error message

Tags: php

When executing this function I have "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" :

```
function getUserInfo() { 
    global $db;

    $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT u.id, u.active, u.date, u.last_modified, u.username, u.country, 
                     u.gender, u.birthday, u.avatar
                FROM session s
                INNER JOIN users u
                    ON s.sid = :sid
                    AND s.userid = u.id ');

    $sql->execute( array(':sid' => session_id()) );

    $userdata = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (empty($userdata)) {
        $userdata = FALSE;
    }

    return $userdata;
}
```

Comment: $db doesn't contain connection object

Comment: Instead of getting the object using `global` just pass the `$db` through your function as `getUserInfo($db)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$db hasn't been initialized. For example (where the DB_* constants are replaced with your values):

```
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Place this in your code and you will see that $db is not an object:

```
    var_dump($db);
```